# Hive - Filter on Map data type column stuck

Tags: dictionary, types, hive, hadoop-yarn

We have a table with one year of data in daily date partition. Each day has 100 billion rows. The table has a map data type column which holds a 100000+ key-value pair. All I need is min(date) based on the two map column filter. YARN is stuck with deciding a number of mapper for this query. I only see the below message when I invoke the query and it stuck for more than 30+ minutes. Then I killed the job. Is there a way to optimize and run the query?

Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=

```
Query:
select min(data_dt) from my_db.logs
where txttype = 'abcd'
and mapfields['page_name'] in ('a','b','c','d','e','d')
-- Total 50 page names
and mapfields['usedIn'] like '%Group%'
and (ctry like 'aa%' or ctry like 'bb%' or ctry like 'cc%')
;
```

Comment: could you show us you select query?

Comment: @GaurangShah I added the query in the post

Comment: from you error it seems like your query endup creating too many reducers, the best way to check your query plan using `explain` keyword. However for now, can you set following thing and run the query again `set hive.exec.reducers.max=10` `set set mapreduce.job.reduces=2`

Comment: 100*10^9*365 = Like 3.6 trillion rows (!) full scan in a single query? Consider redesigning something. Partition by `ctry` and use without like if possible. IMHO it is quite normal to think >30 min calculating the number of mappers for such a big data

Comment: @GaurangShah When I run the query for 15 days, I see 349558 of mappers and 1 reducer. And it took 58 minutes to execute the query.